# How to make parallel this for loop in OpenMP?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to run the loop in parallel by adding "#pragma omp parallel for",but this did not work any suggestions to how i can parallel this loop?

```
#pragma omp parallel for
   for (p = split; *p != 0; p++) if (*p == ' ') *p = '0';
```

Comment: Please add environment you're using for your build. This looks like compilation or a define is not set correctly.

Comment: Any reason you spammed the Java-tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For OpenMP to parallelize the loop, the number of loop iterations must be determinable in advance. In this particular case, you'd have to determine the string length first:

```
size_t len = strlen(split);
#pragma omp for
for ( size_t p = 0 ; p < len; ++p ) if (split[p] == ' ') split[p] = '0';
```

It's very doubtful that you'll gain any performance benefit from parallelization for this example though.